# What is the specific use of Pivot table in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, pivot

Im curious what is the distinct use of pivot table in database? I mean, how is it apply in real life.

Comment: Transposing rows into columns.

Comment: You can find plenty of question on here asking about performing pivots (and unpivots). Although some are clearly trivial/homework level, there are plenty that appear to be about real world problems.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot query help us to generate an interactive table that quickly combines and compares large amounts of data. We can rotate its rows and columns to see different summaries of the source data, and we can display the details for areas of interest at a glance. It also help us to generate Multidimensional reporting.

for more information visit:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx